# Casting List<T> - covariance/contravariance problem

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, covariance, contravariance

Given the following types:

```
public interface IMyClass { }
public class MyClass : IMyClass { }
```

I wonder how can I convert a `List<MyClass>` to a `List<IMyClass>`? I am not completely clear on the covariance/contravariance topics, but I understand that I cannot just plainly cast the List because of that.

I could come up with this trivial solution only; lacking any elegance, wasting resources:

```
...
public List<IMyClass> ConvertItems(List<MyClass> input)
{
   var result = new List<IMyClass>(input.Count);
   foreach (var item in input)
   {
       result.Add(item);
   }
   return result;
}
....
```

How can you solve it in a more elegant/performant way?

(*Please, mind that I need .NET 2.0 solution, but for completeness, I would be happy to see the more elegant solutions using newer framework versions, too.*)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to use [`ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx):

```
List<IMyClass> converted = original.ConvertAll<IMyClass>(x => x);
```

Even if you're using .NET 2, you can use lambda syntax if you're using VS2008 or higher. Otherwise, there's always anonymous methods:

```
List<IMyClass> converted = original.ConvertAll<IMyClass>(
    delegate (MyClass x) { return x; });
```

In .NET 3.5 you could use LINQ with `Cast`, `OfType` or even just `Select`:

```
var converted = original.Cast<IMyClass>().ToList();
var converted = original.OfType<IMyClass>().ToList();
var converted = original.Select(x => (IMyClass) x).ToList();
```

In .NET 4.0 you can use `ToList` directly without an intermediate cast, due to the covariance of `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
var converted = original.ToList<IMyClass>();
```

Comment: That's a sneaky use of covariance; very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Does it need to be a list?  An `IEnumerable` solution could be more efficient:

```
 public IEnumerable<IMyClass> ConvertItems(List<MyClass> input)
 {
    foreach (var item in input)
    {
        yield return (IMyClass)item;
    }
 }
```

Comment: It is worth saying that you don't necessarily need to do this to use an IEnumerable solution. The method could just do `return input;`. It would mean that the underlying object was still the list and so you could go back to it - a problem you don't find with the above method. But Covariance means that a direct cast to `IEnumerable<IMyClass>` is very possible. Not sure if this is a new change since this answer was first made 7 years ago. I don't keep track of the history of c# but it is certainly valid now. :)

Answer (score 0):

(.NET 3.5 solution)

```
List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass> { ... };
List<IMyClass> converted = list.Cast<IMyClass>().ToList();
```

Comment: converted is an `IEnumerable<IMyClass>` and not a `List<IMyClass>`

Comment: OP asked "how can I convert ... to a `List<IMyClass>`", and you don't convert to a `List<T>` but an `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @CodeInChaos: You're right, that was my first version and lately I switched to `IEnumerable<T>`. Rolled back. Thanks