# Casting an object to a base collection

Tags: c#, .net

I'm not totally convinced this is possible, but here goes. I have a method returning an object, although the actual type is Collection. Now, I can easily cast the object into the collection using

```
var myCollection = myObject as Collection<MyClassA>;
```

However the problem I have is that `Collection<MyClassA>` could alternatively be `Collection<MyClassB>` or `Collection<MyClassC>`. All of these `MyClassX`'s are inherited from `MyBaseClass`, so ideally I would like to be able to do something like

```
var myCollection = myObject as Collection<MyBaseClass>;
```

However this throws an exception when casting. Is it possible to do this in anyway? I understand that it may be within .Net 4?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:
OK - The answers so far are very useful, however they only solve the second part of the solution - converting/casting collections.

I am still unsure as to how I should initially cast the object to a collection (without the use of a huge if statement for each of the possible types)

Comment: It's a C# 4.0 feature, and has nothing to do with .NET 4.0.

Comment: @John: You wouldn't be able to cast as `Collection<MyBaseClass>`, regardless of whether it's a feature of .NET4 or C#4.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting List<T> - covariance/contravariance problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931789/casting-listt-covariance-contravariance-problem). Please read Jon Skeet's answer, it will perfectly match to your case.

Comment: @LukeH: I'm aware that covariance and contravariance only work for interfaces and delegates. When I said "It's" a C# 4.0 feature, I was presuming that the OP was thinking about covariance and contravariance features of C# 4.0, which are not .NET features.

Comment: @John: I assumed that you would be aware of it. My comment was really just for the OP's benefit, in case they misinterpreted your comment as saying that a cast to `Collection<MyBaseClass>` would be possible in C#4. But (and here's a genuine nitpick) since C#4 shipped as part of .NET4, it is, imo, legitimate to say that variance in C#4 is part of the .NET4 feature-set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only supported with `IEnumerable<T>` in .NET 4. Check out the difference in the signatures:

[`IEnumerable<T>`:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx)

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
```

[`Collection<T>`:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx)

```
public class Collection<T> : IList<T>, 
ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

That `out` keyword in the type parameter is what tells .NET to support variance.

Comment: I think using .OfType<>() and a common interface will work as well, for pre-.NET 4.0 users.

Comment: Thanks for this part of the answer. The problem I still have is that at the start I have a basic object which is an unknown generic type - I would still need to convert the object to either a Collection or IEnumerable first? Ideally I need to straight convert the object to the IEnumerable<IMyClass> from the offset.

Comment: @code4life, `Cast<T>()` would be the preferred route for `MyClass` to `IMyClass` conversions. It's more obvious your intent. Use `OfType<T>()` when you actually need to filter before converting, as in the case of a mixed source.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution: you could use interfaces and generics to get what you want.

```
public interface IMyClass
{
}

public class MyClassA : IMyClass
{
}

public class MyClassB : IMyClass
{
}

public class MyClassC : IMyClass
{
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var listA = new List<IMyClass>{new MyClassA{}, new MyClassA{}};
    var listB = new List<IMyClass> { new MyClassB { }, new MyClassB { } };
    var listC = new List<IMyClass> { new MyClassC { }, new MyClassC { } };

    List<IMyClass> genericList = listA.Cast<IMyClass>().ToList();
}
```

Something like this will compile properly and also allow you to assign different lists of any types that implement the common interface, to the same variable (in this case `genericList`.

Answer (score 1):

Before I had access to .NET 4 I wrote an extension method that achieved this:

```
public static IEnumerable<U> CastCollection<T, U>(this IList<T> items) where U : class
{
   var collection = new List<U>();
   foreach (var item in items)
   {
      if (item is U)
      {
           var newItem = item as U;
           collection.Add(newItem);
      }
  }
  return collection;
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
var myCollection = myObject.CastCollection<MyClassA, MyBaseClass>();
```

`myCollection` will be an `IEnumerable<MyBaseClass>` in this case.

Comment: In this method, you're silently discarding items that cannot be cast, which is non-intuitive given the name. What you wrote is essentially reinventing `OfType<T>`, which will filter an existing sequence to return and convert items that match a given type. What your name implies is a reinvention of `Cast<T>`, which will throw an exception if something cannot be converted.

Comment: The method certainly has its faults, but it met the requirements of the project. I was not aware of the uses for `OfType<T>`, otherwise I would have used that.  I'm glad you pointed out its pitfalls though, thank you.

Comment: I've reinvented quite a few wheels, myself. I always feel proud of myself right up until someone points me to the original.

Comment: @Anthony like building a full-featured, pluggable JSON serializer-deserializer? I was a rockstar for 2 days. Oops. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done by casting the collection as a whole. However, you can cast the individual elements to a new collection. Look at LINQ's Cast<> extension method.