# Casting a C# List<>

Tags: reflection, c#-3.0

I have what seems to be a simple problem but one that I can't seem to find answers to. I have a class with properties. One of those properties returns a List. I have a method that cycles through all properties of any kind of class and produces a TreeNode for that class (a communication log application). When I come across the property identified as a List, I don't know how to cast the property.GetValue properly. the property.PropertyType is known but what ever I try, I  get a compilation error or a runtime error.

Here is what I'm trying to do...

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
{
    if(prop.PropertyType.Namespace == "System.Collections.Generic")
    {
        List<object> oList = prop.GetValue(data, null);
        MessageBox.Show(oList.Count.ToString())
    }
}
```

If I put a breakpoint on the GetValue line, the prop parameter knows that it's a list of "myclass" items with three elements. I just can't cast it to either a list of objects (which would be fine) or cast it to a list of actual "myclass" elements which would be even better. How do I cast the return value of PropertyInfo.GetValue (an object) to its List?

Comment: If you do var oList = prop.GetValue() does it return the correct type?

Comment: Related to [Casting List<T> - covariance/contravariance problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931789/casting-listt-covariance-contravariance-problem).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it's not enough (or needed in this case at all) to check the namespace. You can check if prop.PropertyType is an instance of [ICollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.aspx) (you can use [IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx)). I'm suggesting ICollection because you only seem to care about the Count.

You can then cast it to an ICollection (non-generic) and run [Enumerable.Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx), like:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> res = ((ICollection)prop.GetValue(data,null)).Cast<MyClass>();
MessageBox.Show(res.Count().ToString());
```

The advantage over converting directly to List is that this will work with any collection. But if you don't need that, you can try what the other answer suggests.

Comment: You are the man (gender inspecific of course)!!! The IEnumerable is what I needed. I can get away with casting to a list of objects as the recursive function takes objects rather than specific class types. This works perfectly. Thanks much. As for the IsAssignableFrom.... how do I use that?

Comment: Try if (ICollection.IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType)) { ... }

Answer (score 1):

did you try

```
prop.GetValue(data, null) as List<YourClass>;
```

Comment: The heart of the problem is that "YourClass" will vary with each different object that I'm trying to log. The property knows what kind of list it is but I can't put anything programatic in the <>. If I do, I get a compiler error. I have this problem with the other answers too. If I want to do this by checking the property's type that would be the way to go but I can't seem to find what to put in the <> that will work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want contravariance.

Are you trying to do so?

```
List<object> list = (List<Product>)object;
```

`List<object>` and `List<Product>` wouldn't be treated as the same type.

C# 4.0 introduced covariance and contravariance for interface and delegate generic parameters, but anyway, `IList<T>` doesn't have contravariance.

In my humild opinion, I believe you'll need to reconsider your object graph!

PD: Just comment out if you want guidance for that!