# Return a list of abstract class

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Casting List<T> - covariance/contravariance problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931789/casting-listt-covariance-contravariance-problem)

I have classes defined as below

```
public abstract class AbstractDType  
{  
     protected abstract string Num1 { get; set; }  
     protected abstract string Num2 { get; set; }  
}

public class AD1 : AbstractDType  
{  
   public string Num1 { get;  set; }  
   public string Num2 { get;  set; }  
   public string Num3 { get; set;  }  
}  

public class AD2 : AbstractDType  
{  
   public string Num1 { get;  set; }  
   public string Num2 { get;  set; }  
   public string Num3 { get; set;  }   
}  

public abstract class DTypeStrategy  
{  
   protected virtual List<AbstractDType> GetData()  
   {  
          return new List<AD1>();  
   }    
}
```

I would like to return a list of PD1 (concrete type) in GetData() method. However the above code threw a casting  error . `List<AbstractDType>` cannot be converted to `List<PD1>`.  How do I fix this error so that I could return concrete in GetData method.

There are other derived classes that inherited from DTypeStrategy  which would be implementing GetData() such as below : ( I am assuming that I'll get the same casting error here as well )

```
public class MyDraw : DTypeStrategy  
{  
   public override List<AbstractDType> GetData()  
   {  
          return new List <AD2>();  
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your actual goal here?   If you really just want to return a list from GetData that *contains* AD1, you can do that:

```
protected virtual List<AbstractDType> GetData()  
{  
      var stuff = new List<AbstractDType>();
      stuff.Add( new AD1() );
      return stuff;
}
```

But if you really want to return a list of a concrete type, then, well, you can't do that - and it points to a flaw in your design.  Think of the calling code *if this were possible*:

```
public void Victim(DTypeStrategy strat)
{
    List<AbstractDType> list = strat.GetData();
    //oops, the list is actually a list<AD1>, so this throws:
    list.Add( new AD2() );
}
```

Ask yourself:

- Why do I want to return a specialized list rather than one of AbstractDType?
- Why should it be a List at all, and not an IEnumerable?

If you MUST have a specialized List for some reason, use a generic method:

```
public class DTypeStrategy<T> where T: AbstractDType
{
    //not sure a concrete here is a good idea, but you get the point...
    public virtual List<T> GetData()
    {
       return new List<T>();
    }
}

public class MyDraw : DTypeStrategy<AD2>
{
   public override List<AD2> GetData()
   {
      return new List<AD2>();
   }
}
```

If you don't need a `List<T>`, then you can probably abuse c#'s [covariant generic interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) to do this - but again, I'd look at your design *first*.

Comment: I am using Strategy Pattern to create concrete objects based on typeID. Each concrete object's GetData() method would return a specific list such as List of AD1 , AD2 or AD3. AD1, AD2 and AD3 inherited from AbstractDType. DTypeStrategy would have GetData() method with default behaviour.

Comment: @Alan B In a strategy pattern, the code calling your strategies shouldn't need to know what the concrete List `GetData` is returning, so the top snippet would be what you want - create the list from the abstract and add instances of subclasses to it.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem from the code you've posted that by the time you inherit `DTypeStrategy` you know which concrete class you want to return.

Therefore you can turn `DTypeStrategy` into a generic class

```
public abstract class DTypeStrategy <T> where T:AbstractDType  
{  
   protected abstract List<T> GetData();
}
```

and then this works:

```
public class MyDraw : DTypeStrategy <AD2> 
{  
   public override List<AD2> GetData()  
   {  
          return new List <AD2>();  
   } 
}
```